# How to get id value of a selected radio button in a gsp page to grails controller/domain class

Tags: grails, gsp, radiobuttonlist

USING: grails 1.3.7 fyi.

```
<g:each var="name" in="${nameList}">
 <li>${name.first}</li>
 <input id="Add" type="radio" name="nameMod" value="${name.first}"/>Add
 <input id="Modify" type="radio" name="nameMod" value="${name.first}"/>Modify
 <g:hiddenField name="action" value="${nameMod.id} "/>
</g:each>
```

So this is what I'm trying to do: I know how to get the value of the radio buttons but, I also need to know which button was pressed. As you can see from above, I tried to set the ID of the radio button to the action (Add/Modify), but I get an error stating that `.id` is not a valid property. I know how to test for a radio button being selected or not in jQuery, but I'm not sure how to get the value from jQuery to a controller or domain class.

Is there another way of doing this? Basically I need to know the action and the name, so that I can update the database.

Thanks for any advice! (Is it okay for me to say this? edit away!! ;))

Comment: The error is coming from your hiddenField.  It is trying to get the id property of nameMod.  I think you may want `value=${name.id}` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with jQuery, but this would be a good case for using a command object:

View:

```
<g:each var="name" in="${nameList}" status="i">
  <li>${name.first}</li>
  <input type="radio" name="nameAction[${i}]" value="add"/>Add
  <input type="radio" name="nameAction[${i}]" value="modify"/>Modify
  <g:hiddenField name="name[${i}]" value="${name.first} "/>
</g:each>
```

Command Object:

```
class NameCommand {
    List<String> nameAction = []
    List<String> name = []
}
```

Controller:

```
def theAction = { NameCommand foo ->
    foo.nameAction.eachWithIndex { val, index ->
        if (val == "add") {
            whateverService.add(foo.name[index]) 
        }
        else {
            whateverService.modify(foo.name[index])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add some class (used only in javaScript) to your radio button, and use it!

```
<g:each var="name" in="${nameList}">
 <li>${name.first}</li>
 <input id="Add" type="radio" name="nameMod" class="f_radioButtonGroup" value="${name.first}"/>Add
 <input id="Modify" type="radio" name="nameMod" class="f_radioButtonGroup" value="${name.first}"/>Modify
 <g:hiddenField name="action" value="${nameMod.id} "/>
</g:each>
```

and in javaScript function

```
function getCheckedItemNumber() {
    var result;
    var radioButtons = $(".f_radioButtonGroup");
    for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
        if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
            result = radioButtons[i].value;
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
 <g:each var="name" in="${nameList}">
   <li>${name.first}</li>
  <input id="Add" type="radio" name="selectedAction" value="add"/>Add
  <input id="Modify" type="radio" name="selectedAction" value="modify"/>Modify
  <g:hiddenField name="nameMod" value="${name.first} "/>
 </g:each>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably going to have to do a little more with the radio button names since you are iterating over an unknown number of names. You could have 100 radio buttons in a group called `nameMod` - then you could only select one of those 100 radio buttons - which I don't think is what you want.

When I've had things like this I've done them like this:

```
<g:each var="name" in="${nameList}">
  <li>${name.first}</li>
  <input type="radio" name="nameMod_${name.id}" value="add"/>Add
  <input type="radio" name="nameMod_${name.id}" value="modify"/>Modify
  <g:hiddenField name="name_${name.id}" value="${name.first} "/>
</g:each>
```

That will give you one radio group per name and allow you to access them in the controller individually.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way: 
**just declare a string with name** `selectedAction` **(must match with name of radio button in gsp) in your domain class**. That's it, GORM will take care of binding process; the value of the selected radio button will be put into `selectedAction` (domain class field).

You need to do nothing more than that. Whew!